# How to send any data over python3 sockets?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I am new in python sockets, and I want to write a `send(data: any)`, which will any types of data over a socket, but there are some problems. I did it like this:

```
    def send(self, data: any):
        if type(data) is not bytearray:
            b = bytearray()
            b.extend(map(ord, data))
            self.__s__.sendall(b) # s is the socket
        else:
            self.__s__.sendall(data)
```

```
    def recv(self, len_of_packet: int):
        buf = bytearray()
        while len(buf) < len_of_packet:
            buf = buf.append(self.__s__.recv(len_of_packet - len(buf)))
        return buf
```

but it gives me

```
    buf = buf.append(self.__s__.recv(len_of_packet - len(buf)))
TypeError: 'bytes' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I did this loop in `recv()` because TCP sockets can send only part of the data, I also did `if type(data) is not bytearray:` because `sendall()` wants only bytes, but for some reason it does not work. I tried to use `bytes()`, but there were another errors. **So, what is the most pythonic way to send any data and receive it all at the other end?** Particularly i want to send pictures and text. And how to handle the fact `recv()` returns str(), which I want to be bytes?

Calling example:

```
image = open('image.jpg', 'rb').read()
con.send(image)
```

and at the other end:

```
image = con.recv(size)
```

Comment: This isn't related but don't invent dunder names like: `__s__` and please *always* use the generic python tag for all python questions

Answer (score 1):

You are misinterpreting how bytearray.append() works:

> *help(bytearray.append)*
>
> ```
> B.append(int) -> None
> ```
>
> Append a single item to the end of B.

You want to use bytearray.extend():

> *help(bytearray.extend)*
>
> ```
> B.extend(iterable int) -> None
> ```
>
> Append all the elements from the iterator or sequence to the end of B.

There are a few other problems with you code. E.g. a TCP socket's recv will return an empty bytearray once the connection is closed. You'd have an infinite loop in this case if the connection was disrupted prematurely.

Answer (score -1):

I have probably fixed the issue by making functions like this:

```
def send(self, data: any):
    if type(data) is int:
        data = str(data)
    if type(data) is bytes or type(data) is bytearray:
        self.__s__.sendall(data)
    else:
        b = bytearray()
        b.extend(map(ord, data))
        self.__s__.sendall(b)

def recv(self, len_of_packet: int):
    data = bytearray()
    while len(data) < len_of_packet:
        packet = self.__s__.recv(len_of_packet - len(data))
        if not packet:
            return None
        data.extend(packet)
    return data
```

At least this code solves my problem because I've successfully sent a picture over a socket